# JS code for SharePoint "open in explorer" function

Tags: javascript

I have attempted to use the following code to add a link to use the "Open in Explorer" option in SharePoint 2013

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var CurrentSiteURL = document.location.pathname.split("/").slice(1,2).toString();
var ExplorerViewURL = "\u002f"+CurrentSiteURL+"\u002fShared\u0020Documents";
var LinkText = "Open Shared Documents in Explorer View"
</script>

<a onclick="NavigateHttpFolder(ExplorerViewURL, 'blank');" href="#">
<img style="height: 24px; width: 24px; border: 0px; padding-right: 5px;" alt="Open in Explorer" src="/Style Library/client/folder_yellow_explorer.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(LinkText);</script
></a>
```

However, i'm at a loss which elements must be changed in order that the code will work for a specific document library or folder. can you please give me a clue what elements must be changed? thanks,.